# Open link in new tab in firefox-extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have developed a webapp to use it as Firefox extension. In Firefox I include it with an iframe like this

```
<iframe src="http://mywebapp.com" flex="2" id="browserTable" name="table_frame"/>
```

Now I want to have some outgoing links in my app. If I just use normal link markup like

```
<a href="http://mywebapp.com/contact">Contact</a>
```

the link is opened in the iframe that is small in space since it is in the sidebar. Is there any way to open it in a new tab in the main browser window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `target` attribute allows you to specify which window to open a link in.  You have these special keywords you can place in the attribute:

```
    _blank - new window
    _self - same window (default)
    _parent - the window which opened the current window, or the parent frame in a frameset
    _top - overload the entire page, usually used in a frame context 
   "string" - in the window with an id of "string", or a new window if "string" is not the id of a current window
```

So, here is your HTML:

```
<a href="http://mywebapp.com/contact" target="_blank">Contact</a>
```

**EDIT** Did some research after our discussion in comments, and found this snippet:

```
var myUrl = "http://mesh.typepad.com";
var tBrowser = top.document.getElementById("content");
var tab = tBrowser.addTab(myUrl);
// use this line to focus the new tab, otherwise it will open in background
tBrowser.selectedTab = tab;
```

Source: http://mesh.typepad.com/blog/2004/11/creating_a_new_.html

Let me know if that works out... curious myself, but my current FF environment is not one in which I can easily experiment with extension dev, and I don't want to change things to try.

Comment: hm that opens a new ff window, would like to have tab, do you think this is possible? maybe with css3 :D http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/ gonna check this out

Comment: A new window?? Wha?  Should not be.  This can be affected by a client-side option in Firefox, check Tools->Options, on the 'Tabs' tab there is a series of checkboxes.  One is titled "Open new windows in a tab instead".  Is this checked?  If not, that is why it is opening a new window.  There is no way to "force" a user to open a tab if their client options are configured in this fashion.  Otherwise, the target attribute should be opening a new tab.

Comment: would be great if we could focus the opened tab

Comment: The last line is supposed to do that.  I presume it isn't.  Let me know... I can read through the docs and try to find out how to do it.  Again - I'm curious for my own sake, and not set up to test it.  Guinea Pig for me! :)

Comment: FYI `target="_content"` should make a sidebar link open in the current browser tab.