# Open a link in new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm using this javascript code in firefox addon:

```
window.open(link);
```

It opens a link in a new Window. I was looking for function to open a link in a new tab but haven't found it. I found that this is in defined in firefox settings. I looked into my settings and found that I have defined "open in new tab" for everything (in Tabmixplus extension too).
Do you know how to open a link in new tab?

thank you

Comment: Oh look, related questions, [Open Link in new tab in ff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110129/open-link-in-new-tab-in-firefox-extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addTab? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/addTab

Comment: thank you. `gBrowser.addTab(link);` opens link in background tab. Can I open it foreground too?

Comment: Sure just set it as the selected tab: `gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab(link)`.